# How to get uk districts through geoname webservice

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, bing-maps, geonames

I am trying to retrieve following information from geonames web services;

City, State, Province(ISO3166-2) , Country Name , Country Code

example: Houston, Texas, TX , USA , US

I have come across this example on google 
`http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/g4stl/` and i have tried to amend it as per my requirements but no luck.

Is there any way to call one web service to get all the information.

If try this link by passing 'Houston' as a parameter then i don't get country name.

```
http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=houston&maxRows=10&style=full&lang=es&username=demo
```

This works if i pass lat & lng but user will passing city name or country name. `http://api.geonames.org/countrySubdivision?lat=29.76&lng=-95.36&username=demo`

Answer (score 0):

Since you add the Bing Maps tag on your question, with Bing Maps REST Geocode API, you can have a result that includes the fully structured address also with every information in dedicated properties, see the MSDN for more details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx

You also have the `include` parameters that you can set to `ciso2` to retrieve the iso code for the country.

You can also retrieve the geographic data using the Geodata API, here is a sample request in UK to retrieve the county borders as a geometry:

https://platform.bing.com/geo/spatial/v1/public/geodata?spatialFilter=GetBoundary(51.324114,%200.720544,1,%27AdminDivision2%27,1,1,%27en%27,%27UK%27)&key=YOURKEY

More information about geodata API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306801.aspx

Comment: Do you need the geometry of the uk district? If so, you can use the geodata API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306801.aspx

Comment: doesn't do uk districts

Comment: Assuming that you want to retrieve the equivalent of the geometry corresponding to the county (or any other level of division, you can configure it based on the request), here is a working example in uk: 
https://platform.bing.com/geo/spatial/v1/public/geodata?spatialFilter=GetBoundary(51.324114,%200.720544,1,%27AdminDivision2%27,1,1,%27en%27,%27UK%27)&key=YOURKEY